# CGI does not execute the program

Tags: server, apache2, cgi

Newbie developer on Ubuntu I use the Eiffel language

I tried a simple example of the EiffelWeb library based on cgi-bin

I added to apache2.conf the following lines

```
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin/>
Options ExecCGI
Require all granted
</Directory>

ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/"
```

I have a simple Webpage with a button to execute a program (named web)

I copied the web binary to the /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ directory

Apache seems to find the web program but open a save dialog window

i get the message (in french sorry !)
[Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORonf.png)

I dont want to open the binary file web but to execute it

How to do that ?

The body section of the simple Webpage :

```
     <form action="/cgi-bin/web" method="post" name="info">
       <ul>
         <input name="name" size="50">
       </ul>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is the CGI module enabled? If not, use these commands:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```